# Select items with the same foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a question regarding Linq in C#.

Let's say that I have 3 tables "Company", "Employee" and "Job".

```
Company
--------
Id - int (PK)
Name - string
```

```
Employee
--------
Id - int (PK)
CompanyId - int (FK on Company.Id)
Name - string
```

```
Job
--------
Id - int (PK)
CompanyId - int (FK on Company.Id)
EmployeeId - int (FK on Employee.Id)
Name - string
```

Something like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHRTE.png)

The important thing is that every `work` must be connected to a `company` but not necessarily to an employee. However, each `employee` must be connected to a `company`. For example we can have racord like that:

```
Company
--------
Id     Name
1      'A'
2      'B'
3      'C'
```

```
Employee
--------
Id     CompanyId     Name
1          1         'A'
2          1         'B'
3          2         'C'
```

```
Job
--------
Id     CompanyId     EmployeeId     Name
1          1             1         'clean'
2          1             2         'wash'
3          2             2         'buy'
4          3            NULL       'sell'
```

And now with linq I would like to get all `jobs` that are assigned to this `employee` and other employees from the same `company`.
So in this case it will should are jobs with id 1 and 2 becouse employee 1 is assigned to company 1 and job with id 2 also has assigned to this company. How could I achieve this using linq but something like this:
`_context.Job.Where (x => x)`

It is important to make only one query to the database.

Tkanks.

Comment: Did you mean `job` when you said `work`?

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL/EF 6.x/EF Core 2.0/EF Core 2.1/EF Core 3.x?

Comment: Oh, yeah my mistake it was supposed to be a "job".
I use EF 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the problem by thinking of it in two steps: find the company for a given employee, find all the jobs for that company:

```
var companyToFind = from e in Employee
                     where e.Id == empToFind
                     select e.CompanyId;

var jobsToFind = from j in Job
                 where companyToFind.Any(cid => cid == j.CompanyId)
                 select j;
```

In LINQ to SQL, EF Core 2.2 and EF Core 3.x the `Any` is translated to an `EXISTS` query in SQL.

Note since you know there should be only one answer to `companyToFind`, sending two queries to the database may be more efficient.

For LINQ to SQL or EF Core 3.x, you could also nest the first query and reduce to a single result:

```
var jobsToFind = from j in Job
                 where (from e in Employee
                     where e.Id == empToFind
                     select e.CompanyId).First() == j.CompanyId
                 select j;
```